# How can I set the value of a Form.Item without a form object in Ant.Design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have custom Form Item component and I want to add hidden input, but I can't update value without Ant Form object (Form.useForm();

```
const selectBefore = (
   <Select
       onChange={value => {/*HOW TO SET NEW VALUE FOR <Input name='term-type'/> ?*/}}
    >
         <Select.Option value="date">Date</Select.Option>
         <Select.Option value="number">Number</Select.Option>
</Select>
);

const InputType = termType === 'date' ? DateInput : Input;

return (
        <>
            <InputType
                addonBefore={selectBefore}
                {...rest}
            />

            <Form.Item
                name='term-type'
                initialValue={termType}
                style={{display: 'none'}}
            >
                <Input
                    type="text"
                    value={termType}
                />
            </Form.Item>
        </>
    );
```

Comment: Could you please add more details why you want to use termType for the value, not the type of the Input?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the Input part altogether instead of keeping it hidden to use its value. Try this:

```
<Select onChange={value => setTermType(value)}}>
     <Select.Option value="date">Date</Select.Option>
     <Select.Option value="number">Number</Select.Option>
</Select>
```

Then you can use `termType` as state, and it will be updated as the `Select` value changes. I suggest that you should add a placeholder or default initial value to `Select` component as

```
<Select defaultValue="date" onChange={value => setTermType(value)}}>
     <Select.Option value="date">Date</Select.Option>
     <Select.Option value="number">Number</Select.Option>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useState` hook and set the value to the `state` and don't use `Form.useForm()` and `Form.Item` at all:

```
const [ termType, setTermType ] = useState("");

...

<Select onChange={value => setTermType(value)}}>
     <Select.Option value="date">Date</Select.Option>
     <Select.Option value="number">Number</Select.Option>
</Select>

...

<Input
    type="text"
    value={termType}
/>
```